# Python 2.7: check if default argument passed with a decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for something i'm not sure how to accompish and can't find an answer.

Lets say I have a function with unknown number of arguments except arg2. Also arg2 doesn't have a fixed argument location:

```
def some_func(arg1, arg2=None, maybe_arg3=None, maybe_not_arg4=None):
    # Do some stuff
```

Now I want to check if arg2 has been passed by the user and replace it from a decorator, eg:

```
def some_dec(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do some stuff
        # check if arg2 is passed and replace
        rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return rv
    return wrapper
```

If it's passed as key/value then it's no problem to get it from kwargs BUT how do I get it if it's passed to args? (Since IDK the number of arguments the function requires)

Comment: FWIW, you cannot define a function like `def foo(bar=None, baz)`. It results in `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`.

Comment: You are right, will fix it in here. Anyways what I meant is whats important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inspect.signature` should give you what you want:

```
def f(x, y, z, a=4):
    pass

import inspect
s = inspect.signature(f)

b = s.bind_partial(2, 4, 6, 8)
'a' in b.arguments

-> True

b = s.bind_partial(2, 4, 6)
'a' in b.arguments

-> False
```

Note that this was introduced at Python version 3.3. On older versions `inspect.getargspec` provides some of the same functionality.

So your decorator could look like:

```
import inspect
import functools

def nag_a(func):
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not 'a' in sig.bind_partial(*args, **kwargs).arguments:
            print("You really should pass 'a', y'know.")
        rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return rv
    return wrapper

def nag_a_27(func):
    spec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    psn = spec.args.index('a')
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not 'a' in kwargs and len(args) <= psn:
            print "You really should pass 'a', y'know."
        rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return rv
    return wrapper

@nag_a
def f(x, y, a=None):
    pass
```

Comment: are we talking about python 2.7? I can't find signatures in inspect.

Comment: @Bogdan Oops, sorry missed that. Yep, you're right it's 3.3+

Comment: @Bogdan Added a 2.7 version. Have a look.

Comment: General concept works great, marked as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can first check the `kwargs` dict for the argument, if it's missing, it's likely going to be the second argument in `args`; check if `args` contains more than two arguments and :

```
def some_dec(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'args2' in kwargs:
             kwargs['args2'] = 'new value' # update value
        elif len(args) > 1:
             args = (args[0], 'new value') + args[2:] # rebuild args with new value
        rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return rv
    return wrapper
```

Comment: I assume all the order arguments after `args2` are optional.

Comment: Also arg2 is not in a fixed location so i can't so that

Comment: @Bogdan If you pass `arg2` as a positional argument it will **always**
 be in the second position, otherwise as a keyword argument, it can be anywhere after positionals.

Comment: What I meant is that whoever writes another function that requires conn will not place it in the 2nd position but in the 5th for example.

Comment: @Bodgan That will only make sense if `arg2` is a keyword argument. Otherwise, a positional in the fifth position, well, it's not the same in your function. Optionals take the exact position in which they appear when they are not passed as keyword argument.

Comment: I used @Paul Panzer concept and evaluated `arg2` position using `inspect.getargspec(func)`. Then I checked if `arg2` exists in `args` and if it did I just replaced it (with a new list since it's a tuple). What I was lacking is the evaluation method for the argument and that's why @Paul Panzer got his question marked as solution. Thank you very much as well for taking your time and helping me ^^